# Getting "undefined" value for a variable outisde a fetch response in react native ?? Please?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, global-variables, fetch

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, {
  Component,
} from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Image,
  ListView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

var REQUEST_URL = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=a667a62ffce29c5d1c5211e316ae43f6';
var REQUEST_URL_BASE_IMG = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w154/'

class Movies extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
      }),
      loaded: false,
    };
    var cast = "";
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData(); //1st collection pulled
  }

  fetchData(){
    fetch(REQUEST_URL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
        this.setState({
          dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(responseData.results),
          loaded: true,
        });
      })
      .done();

  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.loaded) {
      return this.renderLoadingView();
    }

    return (
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderMovie}
        style={styles.listView}
      />
    );
  }

  renderLoadingView() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>
          Loading movies...
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

// fetchData2(movie){
//     fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/'+movie.id+'/credits?api_key=a667a62ffce29c5d1c5211e316ae43f6')
//       .then((response) => response.json())
//       .then((responseJson) => {
//         cast: responseJson.cast;
//       })
//       .catch((error) => {
//         console.error(error);
//       });
// }

  renderMovie(movie,arr) {
                 var arr = [];

                 // I want the cast variable to be displayed on the screen. It is coming either undefined or prints "s1" which indicates no data.

                 fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/'+movie.id+'/credits?api_key=a667a62ffce29c5d1c5211e316ae43f6')
                            .then((response) => response.json())
                            .then((responseJson) => {
                              //cast: responseJson.cast;

                              //test = displaycast(responseJson.cast[0].name);

                              var cast = responseJson.cast[0].name;
                              console.log(cast);
                            })
                            .catch((error) => {
                              console.error(error);
                            });

//      fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/'+movie.id+'/credits?api_key=a667a62ffce29c5d1c5211e316ae43f6')
//         .then((response) => response.json())
//         .then((responseJson) => {
//           this.setState({
//            cast: responseJson.cast,
//            });
//         })
//         .catch((error) => {
//           console.error(error);
//         });

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image
          source={{uri: 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w92/'+ movie.poster_path.replace(/\//g,"")}}
          style={styles.thumbnail}
        />
        <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{movie.title}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.year}>{cast}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  rightContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 20,
    marginBottom: 8,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  year: {
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  thumbnail: {
    width: 53,
    height: 81,
  },
  listView: {
    paddingTop: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Movies', () => Movies);
```

This is my code. My main concern is that I am getting the response from `fetchData` inside the `renderMovie` perfectly and storing it in cast variable. But if I try to access cast variable outside fetch. It shows undefined or empty string.

The entire point of not having this fetch with earlier is because I want to use the fetch response of 1st fetch Operation to get move.id and use it in the 2nd fetch request to get more details.

Answer (score 0):

That's happening because JavaScript is asynchronous. I'd recommend doing something like your other fetch and set a loading state to know when you've fetched the cast and use that to render.

Comment: I tried doing that but it throws an error when I try to set state. 
If you could kindly provide a sample, that would help.

Comment: Maybe you should do it in .then((responseData) => { of fetchData()? You can nest fetch statements.

Comment: I want to use the 1st response to generate the 2nd request and just set cast variable after the 2nd response. So my 1st request runs just once but my 2nd request should execute for the number of records in 1st request. I dont understand how nested fetch would help in that case. A short snippet would help

Comment: Use a for loop.